# Yocto: Add debug mode for a bsp recipe which is using a scc file

Tags: yocto, yocto-recipe

I need to add debug mode (enable/disable a few kernel config) to a kernel recipe. The recipe resides under `recipes-kernel`.

We have this inside recipe `linux-yocto-onl_5.10.bb`:

```bash
...
SRC_URI += "\
    git://git.yoctoproject.org/yocto-kernel-cache;type=kmeta;name=meta;branch=yocto-5.10;destsuffix=kernel-meta \
    file://my-kmeta;type=kmeta;name=my-kmeta;destsuffix=my-kmeta
"
```

We have this directory structure inside recipe folder:

```
.
└── my-kmeta
    ├── bsp
    │   ├── armel-iproc
    │   │   ├── armel-iproc.cfg
    │   │   ├── armel-iproc.scc
    │   │   ├── ... (some patches)
    │   │   ├── extraconfigs.cfg
    │   │   └── extraconfigs_debug.cfg
    └── ...
```

This is content of `armel-iproc.scc`:

```bash
define KMACHINE armel-iproc
define KTYPE standard
define KARCH arm

patch ...

kconf hardware armel-iproc.cfg
kconf non-hardware extraconfigs.cfg
```

I tried two solution without success:

First I've added another `.scc` file and appended it to `SRC_URI` of the recipe. Inside that scc file just added `kconf` `extraconfigs_debug.cfg`. after baking the recipe, the config file seems copied to the build directory, but inside the .config file in build directory the changes aren't applied.

The second approach is defining two recipes, one for release and another for debug, for this I need to have two `.scc` files: one `armel-iproc.scc` and the other is `armel-iproc_debug.scc`, the second included the first plus `kconf`ing `extraconfigs_debug.cfg`. After baking the debug recipe (by including `armel-iproc_debug.scc` to SRC_URI), I got errors indicating that `bsp/armel-iproc` is not found.

Comment: You may be able to use `KERNEL_FEATURES` to select the appropriate scc/cfg files - e.g. `KERNEL_FEATURES:append = " ${@bb.utils.contains("IMAGE_FEATURES", "mykernel-debug", "armel-iproc_debug.scc", "armel-iproc.scc", d)}"`

Comment: I tested this, but seems it didn't look for `armel-iproc_debug.scc` file. I've added `mykernel-debug` and I can see it in 'bitbake -e IMAGE | grep ^IMAGE_FEATURES'.